# Assign new weights to a layer, PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

For a toy CNN architecture:

```
class LeNet5(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
    # def __init__(self, beta = 1.0):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Trainable parameter for swish activation function-
        # self.beta = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(beta, requires_grad = True))
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels = 1, out_channels = 6, 
            kernel_size = 5, stride = 1,
            padding = 0, bias = False 
        )
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features = 6)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels = 6, out_channels = 16,
            kernel_size = 5, stride = 1,
            padding = 0, bias = False
        )
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features = 16)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(
            in_features = 256, out_features = 120,
            bias = False
        )
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features = 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(
            in_features = 120, out_features = 84,
            bias = False
        )
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features = 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(
            in_features = 84, out_features = 10,
            bias = True
        )
        
        # self.initialize_weights()

        
    def initialize_weights(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            # print(m)
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight)
                
                # Do not initialize bias (due to batchnorm)-
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
                
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                # Standard initialization for batch normalization-
                nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

            elif isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight)
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
    
    
    def swish_fn(self, x):
        return x * torch.sigmoid(x * self.beta)

    
    def forward(self, x):
        
        x = nn.SiLU()(self.pool(self.bn1(self.conv1(x))))
        x = nn.SiLU()(self.pool(self.bn2(self.conv2(x))))
        x = x.view(-1, 256)
        x = nn.SiLU()(self.bn3(self.fc1(x)))
        x = nn.SiLU()(self.bn4(self.fc2(x)))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


model = LeNet5()
```

To access the named parameters/layers:

```
for layer_name, params in model.named_parameters():
    print(f"{layer_name} has {params.size()} params")
'''
conv1.weight has torch.Size([6, 1, 5, 5]) params
bn1.weight has torch.Size([6]) params
bn1.bias has torch.Size([6]) params
conv2.weight has torch.Size([16, 6, 5, 5]) params
bn2.weight has torch.Size([16]) params
bn2.bias has torch.Size([16]) params
fc1.weight has torch.Size([120, 256]) params
bn3.weight has torch.Size([120]) params
bn3.bias has torch.Size([120]) params
fc2.weight has torch.Size([84, 120]) params
bn4.weight has torch.Size([84]) params
bn4.bias has torch.Size([84]) params
fc3.weight has torch.Size([10, 84]) params
fc3.bias has torch.Size([10]) params
'''

# Or-
[x[0] for x in model.named_parameters()]
"""
['conv1.weight',
 'bn1.weight',
 'bn1.bias',
 'conv2.weight',
 'bn2.weight',
 'bn2.bias',
 'fc1.weight',
 'bn3.weight',
 'bn3.bias',
 'fc2.weight',
 'bn4.weight',
 'bn4.bias',
 'fc3.weight',
 'fc3.bias']
"""

[x[0] for x in model.named_parameters()][3]
# 'conv2.weight'

layer_name = [x[0] for x in model.named_parameters()][3]

layer_name
# 'conv2.weight'
```

To assign new values/weights to say 'conv2.weight', I tried:

```
model.state_dict()[layer_name] = torch.randn(16, 6, 5, 5)
```

But this doesn't work, because on checking some values before and after assignment, I see no change

```
model.state_dict()[layer_name][0, 0, :3, :3]
```

If I try to assign new values to 'conv2.weight' layer with

```
layer_name = 'conv2.weight'

# Assign new weights-
model.state_dict()[layer_name] = torch.randn(16, 6, 5, 5)

# Or-
with torch.no_grad():
    model.state_dict()[layer_name] = torch.randn(16, 6, 5, 5)
```

It doesn't work. How can I assign new values to 'conv2.weight'?

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign values to `<layer_name>.weight.data`, not `<layer_name>.weight`. Layer weights are tensors with other info (e.g. gradient) that you don't want to overwrite or change the structure of.

In this example I replace the layer entirely and copy over the weights from the original layer into the new layer.

```
conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(6, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
conv1.weight.data[:,:3,:,:] = model.conv1.weight.data.clone()
conv1.weight.data[:,3:,:,:] = model.conv1.weight.data.clone()
model.conv1 = conv1
```

In this example I directly access and change the original model weights.

```
model.conv1.weights.data = torch.rand(model.conv1.weights.data.shape)
```

And here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
import torchvision.models.resnet50 as resnet
model = resnet(10)
print(model.conv1.weights.data) # parameters are non-zero
model.conv1.weights.data *= 0
print(model.conv1.weights.data) # parameters are now all 0
```

Comment: When I do this, it doesn't work: ```layer_name = 'conv2.weight' model.state_dict()`````[layer_name].data = torch.randn(16, 6, 5, 5)```. I want to avoid manually harcoding ```model.conv1.weight.data``` and wan to use ```layer_name``` variable to access the layer instead?

Comment: layer_name is `conv2`. `weight` is an attribute of the `nn.module` object referenced by  `conv2`, it's not part of the layer name.